# Why are my rows disappearing in my new variable?

Tags: r, variables, categorical-data

I am trying to create a new column from two existing columns. However when I run this code, R wants to fit my variables so they match the number of existing rows. In other words, R removes some rows from the variable I assigned first in order to make room for the rows of the second variable. Is there a simpler way to combine columns so that all rows are included?

Before making new variable:

```
> summary(tdata)
 rumpColor   survivalWithFalcon
 blue :102   killed  :101      
 white:101   survived:102
```

Making new variable:

```
tdata$newvar[tdata$survivalWithFalcon==c("killed")] <- "k"
tdata$newvar[tdata$survivalWithFalcon==c("survived")] <- "s"
tdata$newvar[tdata$rumpColor==c("blue")] <- "b"
tdata$newvar[tdata$rumpColor==c("white")] <- "w"
tdata$newvar<-as.factor(tdata$newvar)
```

After making new variable:

```
> summary(tdata)
 rumpColor   survivalWithFalcon newvar 
 blue :102   killed  :101       b:102  
 white:101   survived:102       w:101
```

But I want "newvar" to have:

```
newvar
k:101
s:102
b:102
w:101
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

A `data.frame` is a list of columns which requires that each column has the same length. You cannot add new rows without adding more data points to the other columns as well.

> Data Frames
>
> Description:
>
> ```
>  The function ‘data.frame()’ creates data frames, tightly coupled
>  collections of variables which share many of the properties of
>  matrices and of lists, used as the fundamental data structure by
>  most of R's modeling software.
> ```
>
> Usage:
>
> ```
>  data.frame(..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE,
>             check.names = TRUE, fix.empty.names = TRUE,
>             stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors())
>  
>  default.stringsAsFactors()
>   Arguments:
>
>  ...: these arguments are of either the form ‘value’ or ‘tag =
>       value’.  Component names are created based on the tag (if
>       present) or the deparsed argument itself.
> ```

What you are doing with the following 2 lines is not adding new rows but replacing the rows that match `rumpColor == Blue` and `rumpColor == White` respectively. This matches all rows that where `survivalWithFalcon == killed` or `survivalWithFalcon = survived` before.

```
tdata$newvar[tdata$rumpColor==c("blue")] <- "b"
tdata$newvar[tdata$rumpColor==c("white")] <- "w"
```

As an alternative I think what you are wishing to achieve:

```
table(tdata$rumpColor, tdata$survivalWithFalcon)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the columns are `factor` class as the `summary` returns the count of only `factor` class and not on `character`.  When we assign new levels to a `factor` column without the levels being present, it would create some NAs.   To prevent this, we can do

```
tdata$newvar <- tdata$survivalWithFalcon
levels(tdata$newvar) <- c(levels(tdata$newvar), "k", "s", "b", "w")
```